# JavaFX: Right click on Mac (Control + Click) not being detected. Any fixes?

Tags: macos, javafx, right-click

I have a list view with items that I am allowing to be double clicked and right clicked (to delete the item). Why does control clicking not work on a mac? Thanks in advance.

Edit: My code is

```
listview.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
       {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
                {
                    if (event.getClickCount() == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Double clicked");
                        System.out.println("clicked on " + listview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                    }
                }
                if(event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY))
                {
                    System.out.println("Right click");
                }
            }
        });
```

My trackpad is set up as secondary button with two finger tap.

Comment: How are you checking for the right click? Post your code here.

Comment: Also, how is your mac configured? Mouse or trackpad? What are the system pref settings?

Comment: Omg thank you so much. I just saw the problem after I typed the edit. Its two finger CLICK not tap.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else looking this up. It is correct that two finger clicking will register as a MouseButton.SECONDARY event, but I think you should also check for Ctrl + MouseButton.PRIMARY since holding the control key is a common method for emulating a right click. So the if statement should be :

```
if ( event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY || e.isControlDown() ) {

    // DO RIGHT CLICK ACTION

}
```